# Why does 3Sum solution variables seem to change out of order?

Tags: python, algorithm

This is the algorithm I am using to solve the 3sum problem on LeetCode.

```
def threeSum(nums):
  res = []
  nums.sort()
  for num in range(len(nums) - 2):
    if num > 0 and nums[num] == nums[num-1]: continue
    start, end = num + 1, len(nums) - 1
    while start < end:
      print(nums[num])
      print(nums[start])
      print(nums[end])
      curSum = nums[num] + nums[start] + nums[end]
      print(curSum)
      if curSum < 0: start += 1
      elif curSum > 0: end -= 1
      else: res.append((nums[num], nums[start], nums[end]))
      while start < end and nums[start] == nums[start+1]:
        start += 1
      while start < end and nums[end] == nums[end-1]:
        end -= 1
      start += 1; end -= 1
  return res

print(threeSum([-1, 0, 1,2,-1,-4]))
```

The problem is when I print out these variables, I am confused about the second set of print statements. My values come out as:

```
nums[num] = -4
nums[start] = 0 
nums[end] = 1
curSum = -3
```

but after the values are

```
nums[num] = -1
nums[start] = -1 
nums[end] = 2
curSum = 0
```

I am confused about how start moved all the way up to 0 but then back to -1 while num didn't increment and end decremented. Then in the next loop, all values seem to go back to what I thought they should be on the second loop. What is occurring here?

Comment: Try adding `print` statements to all the inner loops so you can see how `start` and `end` are changing.

Comment: There are multiple loops: the `for` loop that increments `num`, and the `while` loop that changes `start` and `end`. Which "next loop" are you talking about?

Comment: I think I see now, I added a bunch more print statements. The start variable is based on where the num value is which is what completes the while loop of start < end. Start and end are resetting every time we restart the for loop which is why start and end just seem to skip around. Thank you, its makes sense now